# Prompt date in report with default today's date?

Tags: webi, sap-business-technology-platform

I am using relation SQL as a source for my query as below

```
select * from table where date = ?
```

what I need is when the user runs the report, it should prompt to date parameter. the default date should be the current date and there should be a calendar to select the date.

i am not using any universal here, so don't know what to do?

Comment: So this is free-hand SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to be as close as you can get.

```
select * 
from table 
where date = @Prompt('Enter Date:','D',,Mono,Free,Not_Persistent,,User:0)
```

[image]

Today's date is defaulted, but not selected. Be cautious with clicking on "Now". That will give you today's date with the current system time which is likely not what you want. You could convert your @Prompt function result to a datatype that does not include the time if you want users to be able to click "Now". In my opinion it is simple enough to instruct users to click the highlighted date for today's date.